# Twitch embed autoplay

Tags: html, iframe, embed

I want to embed a twitch stream into my site but I want it so it is not autoplaying when you go to that page. How would I do this in iFrame? I cannot find anywhere on the internets.

`<iframe src="http://www.twitch.tv/civilgamersstream/embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="378" width="620"></iframe><a href="http://www.twitch.tv/civilgamersstream?tt_medium=live_embed&tt_content=text_link" style="padding:2px 0px 4px; display:block; width:345px; font-weight:normal; font-size:10px;text-decoration:underline;">Watch live video from CivilGamersStream on www.twitch.tv</a>`

Answer (score 2):

I will use http://www.twitch.tv/twitch/c/5894318 as an example.
Go there and get the share embed code. It should look a lot like this:

```
<object bgcolor="#000000" data="http://www.twitch.tv/swflibs/TwitchPlayer.swf" height="378" id="clip_embed_player_flash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="620">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/swflibs/TwitchPlayer.swf" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <param name="allowNetworking" value="all" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="channel=twitch&amp;auto_play=false&amp;start_volume=25&amp;videoId=c5894318&amp;device_id=SLJemBs" />
</object>
```

Take that and update `http://www.twitch.tv/swflibs/TwitchPlayer.swf` to `http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/archive_embed_player.swf` and you should get this:

```
<object bgcolor="#000000" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/archive_embed_player.swf" height="378" id="clip_embed_player_flash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="620">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/archive_embed_player.swf" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <param name="allowNetworking" value="all" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="channel=twitch&amp;auto_play=false&amp;start_volume=25&amp;videoId=c5894318&amp;device_id=SLJemBs" />
</object>
```

I have no idea why Twitch is not letting you choose between the two, but that is what I found and it works for me.